# Was Rama sinful?

Tags: ramayana, rama, karma, sin

**Valmiki Ramayana Aranyakanda 63:4**

> I might have definitely, habitually, and desirably committed damnable deeds in my previous births, and now the result of those impious deeds is very much ripened and has fallen on me, whereby I am entering misery after misery...

This verse say that it was the deed of the bad karma of Rama that his wife is kidnapped. Was ram sinful? What sin he committed?

Comment: I could not find this verse in the critical edition of the Valmiki Ramayana. You can find the critical edition below - http://bombay.indology.info/ramayana/welcome.html

Comment: If we understand that Sri Rama was projected by Valmiki as ordinary human only but not as a God, then this verse makes sense.   It is common to humans to lament in this way, when calamities fall on in succession. @Harshit Gangwar

Comment: I don't know about it. But the translation I used have this shloka.http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga63/aranya_63_frame.htm @sriramnarayan k v

Comment: No valmiki ramayana date him as Vishnu avatar. Yudhha  kand 117:13